# How remap ctrl + k to ctrl + v in linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, hotkeys

I use a Dvorak keyboard, and I want to use the shortcut like a Windows/Dvorak.

I've tried to use autokey but doesn't work very well. I'm interested in a solution on Xorg directly, of the style of xmodmap or setxkbmap.

The first step is remap a arbitrary hotkey like a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, and later remap individually each hotkey. Or use the hotkeys the QWERTY in Dvorak directly.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/10980/is-there-a-way-to-use-dvorak-keyboard-layout-but-with-command-keys-mapped-to-qw) (same as yours but for Windows) someone suggested trying a program they wrote for *nix systems and Windows.  [You can find the code and instructions for doing this here.](https://code.google.com/p/dvorak-qwerty/)  From his description, it seems it would do exactly what you want, automatically.